# EF Code First Identity/Info Storage

Tags: c#, classes, entity-framework, properties

I've built this EF for storing data for web scraping. Any ideas? What am I missing?

```
namespace Identity.Core
{
    [Table("Entities")]
    [Description("Entities Common Information")]
    public class Entities
    {
        //Entities
        //123123-123123-123123123-123123     [Entity.EntityUniqueId]
        //John E Doe                            [Entity.Name]
        //Person                                [Entity.Type]
        //Contractor                            [Entity.SubType]

        //Created: 01/24/2015                [Entity.CreatedOn]
        //LastModified: 01/25/2015           [Entity.LastModifiedOn]

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Description("Identity ID Unique for all entities..")]
        public Guid EntityId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string SubType { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastModifiedOn { get; set; }

        public List<Entities.Person> People { get; set; }
        public List<Entities.Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public List<Entities.Business> Businesses { get; set; }


        [Table("Persons")]
        [Description("Person Entity")]
        public class Person
        {
            //// Persons
            // 1123-123-123-123                 [Entity.Person.EntityUniqueId] //Ties to entity root
            // Person ID: 1                     [Entity.Person.PersonId]
            // Salutation:   Mr.                [Entity.Person.Salutation]
            // FirstName:    John               [Entity.Person.FirstName]
            // MiddleName:   E                  [Entity.Person.MiddleName]
            // LastName:     Doe                [Entity.Person.LastName]
            // DateOfBirth:  01/01/1995         [Entity.Person.DOB]
            // Sex:                             [Entity.Person.GenderType] enum
            // Height:       5'9"               [Entity.Person.Height]
            // Weight:       190 lbs            [Entity.Person.Weight]
            // HairColor:    Blond              [Entity.Person.HairColor] enum
            // EyeColor:     Blue               [Entity.Person.EyeColor] enum
            // SSN:          123-34-4444        [Entity.Person.SOCID]
            [Key]
            public int PersonId { get; set; }

            public string SOCID { get; set; }

            public string Salutation { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string MiddleName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }

            public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
            public string Gender { get; set; }

            public string Height { get; set; }
            public string Weight { get; set; }

            public string HairColor { get; set; }
            public string Eyecolor { get; set; }

            public List<WebProfile> WebProfiles { get; set; }
            public List<Business> Businesses { get; set; }
            public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
            public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
            public List<Media> Photos { get; set; }
            public List<Property> PropertyInPossession { get; set; }

        }

        [Table("Property")]
        [Description("Vehicles,Airplanes, Homes, Etc. associated to person")]
        public class Property
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            [Description("Property ID")]
            public int PropertyId { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string SerialNo { get; set; }
            public string Make { get; set; }
            public string Model { get; set; }
            public string VIN { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public string Subtype { get; set; }

            public List<Entities.Person> People { get; set; }
        }

        [Table("WebProfiles")]
        [Description("Yahoo, Facebook, etc..")]
        public class WebProfile
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            [Description("WebProfile ID")]
            public int WebProfileID { get; set; }

            public string Entry { get; set; } // my_yahoo_id

            public string Provider { get; set; }  //yahoo, skype, etc.

            public bool IsActive { get; set; }

            public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
            public DateTime? LastModifiedOn { get; set; }

            public List<Entities.Person> People { get; set; }
        }

        [Table("Phones")]
        [Description("Phone Entity")]
        public class Phone
        {
            //IsActive:     True                [Entity.Phone.IsActive]
            //IsCurrent:    True                [Entity.Phone.IsCurrent]
            //IsVOIP:       False               [Entity.Phone.IsVoIP]
            //Number        (616)666-6666       [Entity.Phone.Number]
            //Carrier:      Verizon             [Entity.Phone.Carrier]
            //Type:         Landline            [Entity.Phone.Type] enum

            public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
            public DateTime? LastModifiedOn { get; set; }

            public bool IsActive { get; set; }
            public bool IsCurrent { get; set; }
            public bool IsVOIP { get; set; }


            [MinLength(3)]
            public int US_NPA { get; set; } //area code

            [MinLength(3)]
            public int US_NXX { get; set; } //Local Telephone Exchange or Rate Center

            [MinLength(4)]
            public int US_SERIAL { get; set; } //serial

            [MaxLength(14)]
            [Key]
            public string FULL_NANPA_NO { get; set; }

            public List<Entities.Person> People { get; set; }
            public List<Entities.Business> Businesses { get; set; }
            public List<Entities.Address> Addresses { get; set; }


        }

        [Table("Businesses")]
        [Description("Business Entity")]
        public class Business
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int BusinessId { get; set; }

            public string CompanyName { get; set; }

            public List<Entities.Person> People { get; set; }
            public List<Entities.Address> Addresses { get; set; }
            public List<Entities.Phone> Phones { get; set; }
        }

        [Table("Addresses")]
        [Description("Address Entity")]
        public class Address
        {

            //// Addresses
            //123                               [Entity.Address.Number]
            //West Street                       [Entity.Address.Street]
            //13245-3333                        [Entity.Address.PostalCode] (string-contains dash)
            //NY                                [Entity.Address.StateCode]  //Ties to State
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int AddressId { get; set; }

            public int Number { get; set; } //123
            public string Street { get; set; }
            public string PostalCode { get; set; }
            public State State { get; set; }

            public List<Entities.Media> Photos { get; set; }

        }

        [Table("States")]
        [Description("State Part of Country Entity")]
        public class State
        {
            //// ISO 3166-2 States
            //NY                                [State.Code] 
            //New York                          [State.Subdivision]
            //state                             [State.Category]
            //US-NY                             [State.ISOCode] [Key] (string)
            //US                                [State.CountryCode] //Ties to Country

            [Key]
            public string ISOCode { get; set; }

            public string Code { get; set; } //NY
            public string SubDivision { get; set; } //New York
            public string Category { get; set; } //state


        }

        [Table("Countries")]
        [Description("Country Part of Address Entity")]
        public class Country
        {
            //// ISO 3166-1 Countries
            //US                                [Country.Code] [Key] (string)
            //United States                     [Country.Name]
            [Key]
            public string Alpha2            { get; set; }

            public string Alpha3            { get; set; }
            public string EnglishShortName  { get; set; }
            public int    NumericCode       { get; set; }
            public string ISO3166_2         { get; set; }
            public string Name              { get; set; }

            public List<State> States { get; set; }
        }

        [Table("Media")]
        [Description("Blob Photos Or Media")]
        public class Media
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int MediaID { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }

            //This stores all media
            public byte[] Binary { get; set; }

            public string contentType { get; set; }

            public string Size { get; set; }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use comments to show what are expected values and where the values are stored, you need to be more accurate.

> ```
> //US                                [State.CountryCode] //Ties to Country
> ```

there is no `CountryCode` property in your `State`.

---

You have a lot of unneeded vertical space which reduces the readability.

---

Using a class named `Property` can lead to confusion. Wouldn't `Belongings` be a better name which distinguish more between the real world and the programming language ?

Answer (score 1):

Some quick remarks:

1. `Entities` isn't a good class name. A class represents an object, and thus a plural name should be avoided. I don't see the point in how you use it here anyway: why create a 250+ line class when you really should have a `BaseEntity` class and separate `Person`, `Property`, etc. classes (and thus files) that inherit from `BaseEntity`. Surely you'll agree that `List<Entities.Person>` isn't looking very nice. Keep classes small and clean; the moment you've got a class that hundreds of lines long you probably need to start refactoring.
2. `SOCID` isn't a good name for a property. Microsoft's rule is to [use Pascal case or camel case for acronyms more than two characters long](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/141e06ef(v=VS.71).aspx), and to [avoid abbreviations in identifiers or parameter names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/141e06ef(v=VS.71).aspx) (if you must use abbreviations, [use camel case for abbreviations that consist of more than two characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/141e06ef(v=VS.71).aspx)).
3. Those same rules also apply to `VIN` and `IsVOIP`.
4. `US_NPA`, `US_NXX`, `US_SERIAL`, `FULL_NANPA_NO`: [DO NOT use underscores, hyphens, or any other nonalphanumeric characters.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx) The rules for acronyms and abbreviations (remark #2) also apply.
5. Like @Heslacher said in his review: `Property` is a confusing name for a class.
6. `ISOCode`: see remark #2.
7. `ISO3166_2`: see remarks #2 and #4.
8. `Media` is a plural name, and thus to be avoided as a class name.
9. `contentType`: [properties should use PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx).