# EF Code First Seed Method for States/Countries Part I

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I am working to complete this even further, but here's what I've got thus far...

([See my other post for the definition.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78905/ef-code-first-identity-info-storage))

```
protected override void Seed(Identity.Console.IdentityDBContext context)
        {
            //Add Country and States...
            context.Countries.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Alpha2,
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "AF", Alpha3 = "AFG", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:AF", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("004"), EnglishShortName = "Afghanistan", Name = "Afghanistan",
        States = new List<Entities.State>() 
        { 
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-BDS",  Code = "AF-BDS", SubDivision = "Badakhshan"                            ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-BDG",  Code = "AF-BDG", SubDivision = "Badghis"                               ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-BGL",  Code = "AF-BGL", SubDivision = "Baghlan"                               ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-BAL",  Code = "AF-BAL", SubDivision = "Balkh"                                 ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-BAM",  Code = "AF-BAM", SubDivision = "Bamyan"                                ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-DAY",  Code = "AF-DAY", SubDivision = "Daykundi"                              ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-FRA",  Code = "AF-FRA", SubDivision = "Farah"                                 ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-FYB",  Code = "AF-FYB", SubDivision = "Faryab"                                ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-GHA",  Code = "AF-GHA", SubDivision = "Ghazni"                                ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-GHO",  Code = "AF-GHO", SubDivision = "Ghōr"                                  ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-HEL",  Code = "AF-HEL", SubDivision = "Helmand"                               ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-HER",  Code = "AF-HER", SubDivision = "Herat"                                 ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-JOW",  Code = "AF-JOW", SubDivision = "Jowzjan"                               ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-KAB",  Code = "AF-KAB", SubDivision = "Kabul"                                 ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-KAN",  Code = "AF-KAN", SubDivision = "Kandahar"                              ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-KAP",  Code = "AF-KAP", SubDivision = "Kapisa"                                ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-KHO",  Code = "AF-KHO", SubDivision = "Khost"                                 ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-KNR",  Code = "AF-KNR", SubDivision = "Kunar"                                 ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-KDZ",  Code = "AF-KDZ", SubDivision = "Kunduz"                                ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-LAG",  Code = "AF-LAG", SubDivision = "Laghman"                               ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-LOG",  Code = "AF-LOG", SubDivision = "Logar"                                 ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-NAN",  Code = "AF-NAN", SubDivision = "Nangarhar"                             ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-NIM",  Code = "AF-NIM", SubDivision = "Nimruz"                                ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-NUR",  Code = "AF-NUR", SubDivision = "Nuristan"                              ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-PKA",  Code = "AF-PKA", SubDivision = "Paktika"                               ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-PIA",  Code = "AF-PIA", SubDivision = "Paktia"                                ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-PAN",  Code = "AF-PAN", SubDivision = "Panjshir"                              ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-PAR",  Code = "AF-PAR", SubDivision = "Parwan"                                ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-SAM",  Code = "AF-SAM", SubDivision = "Samangan"                              ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-SAR",  Code = "AF-SAR", SubDivision = "Sar-e Pol"                             ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-TAK",  Code = "AF-TAK", SubDivision = "Takhar"                                ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-URU",  Code = "AF-URU", SubDivision = "Urozgan"                               ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-WAR",  Code = "AF-WAR", SubDivision = "Maidan Wardak"                         ,  Category = "province"                   },
            new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-ZAB",  Code = "AF-ZAB", SubDivision = "Zabul"                                 ,  Category = "province"                   }
        }
        },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "AX", Alpha3 = "ALA", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:AX", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("248"), EnglishShortName = "Åland Islands", Name = "Åland Islands" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "AL", Alpha3 = "ALB", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:AL", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("008"), EnglishShortName = "Albania", Name = "Albania" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "DZ", Alpha3 = "DZA", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:DZ", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("012"), EnglishShortName = "Algeria", Name = "Algeria" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "AS", Alpha3 = "ASM", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:AS", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("016"), EnglishShortName = "American Samoa", Name = "American Samoa" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "AD", Alpha3 = "AND", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:AD", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("020"), EnglishShortName = "Andorra", Name = "Andorra" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "AO", Alpha3 = "AGO", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:AO", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("024"), EnglishShortName = "Angola", Name = "Angola" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "AI", Alpha3 = "AIA", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:AI", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("660"), EnglishShortName = "Anguilla", Name = "Anguilla" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "AQ", Alpha3 = "ATA", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:AQ", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("010"), EnglishShortName = "Antarctica", Name = "Antarctica" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "AG", Alpha3 = "ATG", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:AG", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("028"), EnglishShortName = "Antigua and Barbuda", Name = "Antigua and Barbuda" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "AR", Alpha3 = "ARG", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:AR", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("032"), EnglishShortName = "Argentina", Name = "Argentina" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "AM", Alpha3 = "ARM", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:AM", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("051"), EnglishShortName = "Armenia", Name = "Armenia" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "AW", Alpha3 = "ABW", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:AW", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("533"), EnglishShortName = "Aruba", Name = "Aruba" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "AU", Alpha3 = "AUS", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:AU", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("036"), EnglishShortName = "Australia", Name = "Australia" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "AT", Alpha3 = "AUT", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:AT", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("040"), EnglishShortName = "Austria", Name = "Austria" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "AZ", Alpha3 = "AZE", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:AZ", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("031"), EnglishShortName = "Azerbaijan", Name = "Azerbaijan" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BS", Alpha3 = "BHS", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BS", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("044"), EnglishShortName = "Bahamas", Name = "Bahamas" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BH", Alpha3 = "BHR", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BH", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("048"), EnglishShortName = "Bahrain", Name = "Bahrain" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BD", Alpha3 = "BGD", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BD", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("050"), EnglishShortName = "Bangladesh", Name = "Bangladesh" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BB", Alpha3 = "BRB", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BB", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("052"), EnglishShortName = "Barbados", Name = "Barbados" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BY", Alpha3 = "BLR", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BY", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("112"), EnglishShortName = "Belarus", Name = "Belarus" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BE", Alpha3 = "BEL", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BE", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("056"), EnglishShortName = "Belgium", Name = "Belgium" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BZ", Alpha3 = "BLZ", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BZ", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("084"), EnglishShortName = "Belize", Name = "Belize" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BJ", Alpha3 = "BEN", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BJ", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("204"), EnglishShortName = "Benin", Name = "Benin" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BM", Alpha3 = "BMU", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BM", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("060"), EnglishShortName = "Bermuda", Name = "Bermuda" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BT", Alpha3 = "BTN", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BT", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("064"), EnglishShortName = "Bhutan", Name = "Bhutan" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BO", Alpha3 = "BOL", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BO", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("068"), EnglishShortName = "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", Name = "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BQ", Alpha3 = "BES", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BQ", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("535"), EnglishShortName = "Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba", Name = "Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BA", Alpha3 = "BIH", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BA", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("070"), EnglishShortName = "Bosnia and Herzegovina", Name = "Bosnia and Herzegovina" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BW", Alpha3 = "BWA", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BW", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("072"), EnglishShortName = "Botswana", Name = "Botswana" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BV", Alpha3 = "BVT", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BV", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("074"), EnglishShortName = "Bouvet Island", Name = "Bouvet Island" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BR", Alpha3 = "BRA", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BR", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("076"), EnglishShortName = "Brazil", Name = "Brazil" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "IO", Alpha3 = "IOT", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:IO", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("086"), EnglishShortName = "British Indian Ocean Territory", Name = "British Indian Ocean Territory" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BN", Alpha3 = "BRN", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BN", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("096"), EnglishShortName = "Brunei Darussalam", Name = "Brunei Darussalam" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BG", Alpha3 = "BGR", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BG", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("100"), EnglishShortName = "Bulgaria", Name = "Bulgaria" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BF", Alpha3 = "BFA", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BF", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("854"), EnglishShortName = "Burkina Faso", Name = "Burkina Faso" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "BI", Alpha3 = "BDI", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:BI", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("108"), EnglishShortName = "Burundi", Name = "Burundi" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "KH", Alpha3 = "KHM", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:KH", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("116"), EnglishShortName = "Cambodia", Name = "Cambodia" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CM", Alpha3 = "CMR", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CM", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("120"), EnglishShortName = "Cameroon", Name = "Cameroon" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CA", Alpha3 = "CAN", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CA", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("124"), EnglishShortName = "Canada", Name = "Canada" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CV", Alpha3 = "CPV", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CV", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("132"), EnglishShortName = "Cabo Verde", Name = "Cabo Verde" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "KY", Alpha3 = "CYM", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:KY", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("136"), EnglishShortName = "Cayman Islands", Name = "Cayman Islands" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CF", Alpha3 = "CAF", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CF", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("140"), EnglishShortName = "Central African Republic", Name = "Central African Republic" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "TD", Alpha3 = "TCD", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:TD", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("148"), EnglishShortName = "Chad", Name = "Chad" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CL", Alpha3 = "CHL", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CL", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("152"), EnglishShortName = "Chile", Name = "Chile" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CN", Alpha3 = "CHN", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CN", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("156"), EnglishShortName = "China", Name = "China" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CX", Alpha3 = "CXR", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CX", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("162"), EnglishShortName = "Christmas Island", Name = "Christmas Island" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CC", Alpha3 = "CCK", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CC", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("166"), EnglishShortName = "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", Name = "Cocos (Keeling) Islands" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CO", Alpha3 = "COL", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CO", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("170"), EnglishShortName = "Colombia", Name = "Colombia" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "KM", Alpha3 = "COM", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:KM", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("174"), EnglishShortName = "Comoros", Name = "Comoros" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CG", Alpha3 = "COG", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CG", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("178"), EnglishShortName = "Congo", Name = "Congo" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CD", Alpha3 = "COD", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CD", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("180"), EnglishShortName = "Congo (Democratic Republic of the)", Name = "Congo (Democratic Republic of the)" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CK", Alpha3 = "COK", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CK", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("184"), EnglishShortName = "Cook Islands", Name = "Cook Islands" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CR", Alpha3 = "CRI", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CR", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("188"), EnglishShortName = "Costa Rica", Name = "Costa Rica" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CI", Alpha3 = "CIV", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CI", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("384"), EnglishShortName = "Côte d'Ivoire", Name = "Côte d'Ivoire" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "HR", Alpha3 = "HRV", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:HR", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("191"), EnglishShortName = "Croatia", Name = "Croatia" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CU", Alpha3 = "CUB", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CU", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("192"), EnglishShortName = "Cuba", Name = "Cuba" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CW", Alpha3 = "CUW", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CW", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("531"), EnglishShortName = "Curaçao", Name = "Curaçao" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CY", Alpha3 = "CYP", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CY", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("196"), EnglishShortName = "Cyprus", Name = "Cyprus" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "CZ", Alpha3 = "CZE", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:CZ", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("203"), EnglishShortName = "Czech Republic", Name = "Czech Republic" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "DK", Alpha3 = "DNK", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:DK", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("208"), EnglishShortName = "Denmark", Name = "Denmark" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "DJ", Alpha3 = "DJI", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:DJ", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("262"), EnglishShortName = "Djibouti", Name = "Djibouti" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "DM", Alpha3 = "DMA", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:DM", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("212"), EnglishShortName = "Dominica", Name = "Dominica" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "DO", Alpha3 = "DOM", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:DO", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("214"), EnglishShortName = "Dominican Republic", Name = "Dominican Republic" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "EC", Alpha3 = "ECU", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:EC", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("218"), EnglishShortName = "Ecuador", Name = "Ecuador" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "EG", Alpha3 = "EGY", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:EG", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("818"), EnglishShortName = "Egypt", Name = "Egypt" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "SV", Alpha3 = "SLV", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:SV", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("222"), EnglishShortName = "El Salvador", Name = "El Salvador" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "GQ", Alpha3 = "GNQ", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:GQ", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("226"), EnglishShortName = "Equatorial Guinea", Name = "Equatorial Guinea" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "ER", Alpha3 = "ERI", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:ER", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("232"), EnglishShortName = "Eritrea", Name = "Eritrea" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "EE", Alpha3 = "EST", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:EE", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("233"), EnglishShortName = "Estonia", Name = "Estonia" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "ET", Alpha3 = "ETH", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:ET", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("231"), EnglishShortName = "Ethiopia", Name = "Ethiopia" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "FK", Alpha3 = "FLK", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:FK", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("238"), EnglishShortName = "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", Name = "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "FO", Alpha3 = "FRO", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:FO", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("234"), EnglishShortName = "Faroe Islands", Name = "Faroe Islands" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "FJ", Alpha3 = "FJI", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:FJ", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("242"), EnglishShortName = "Fiji", Name = "Fiji" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "FI", Alpha3 = "FIN", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:FI", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("246"), EnglishShortName = "Finland", Name = "Finland" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "FR", Alpha3 = "FRA", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:FR", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("250"), EnglishShortName = "France", Name = "France" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "GF", Alpha3 = "GUF", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:GF", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("254"), EnglishShortName = "French Guiana", Name = "French Guiana" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "PF", Alpha3 = "PYF", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:PF", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("258"), EnglishShortName = "French Polynesia", Name = "French Polynesia" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "TF", Alpha3 = "ATF", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:TF", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("260"), EnglishShortName = "French Southern Territories", Name = "French Southern Territories" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "GA", Alpha3 = "GAB", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:GA", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("266"), EnglishShortName = "Gabon", Name = "Gabon" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "GM", Alpha3 = "GMB", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:GM", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("270"), EnglishShortName = "Gambia", Name = "Gambia" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "GE", Alpha3 = "GEO", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:GE", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("268"), EnglishShortName = "Georgia", Name = "Georgia" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "DE", Alpha3 = "DEU", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:DE", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("276"), EnglishShortName = "Germany", Name = "Germany" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "GH", Alpha3 = "GHA", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:GH", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("288"), EnglishShortName = "Ghana", Name = "Ghana" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "GI", Alpha3 = "GIB", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:GI", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("292"), EnglishShortName = "Gibraltar", Name = "Gibraltar" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "GR", Alpha3 = "GRC", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:GR", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("300"), EnglishShortName = "Greece", Name = "Greece" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "GL", Alpha3 = "GRL", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:GL", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("304"), EnglishShortName = "Greenland", Name = "Greenland" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "GD", Alpha3 = "GRD", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:GD", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("308"), EnglishShortName = "Grenada", Name = "Grenada" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "GP", Alpha3 = "GLP", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:GP", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("312"), EnglishShortName = "Guadeloupe", Name = "Guadeloupe" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "GU", Alpha3 = "GUM", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:GU", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("316"), EnglishShortName = "Guam", Name = "Guam" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "GT", Alpha3 = "GTM", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:GT", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("320"), EnglishShortName = "Guatemala", Name = "Guatemala" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "GG", Alpha3 = "GGY", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:GG", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("831"), EnglishShortName = "Guernsey", Name = "Guernsey" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "GN", Alpha3 = "GIN", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:GN", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("324"), EnglishShortName = "Guinea", Name = "Guinea" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "GW", Alpha3 = "GNB", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:GW", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("624"), EnglishShortName = "Guinea-Bissau", Name = "Guinea-Bissau" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "GY", Alpha3 = "GUY", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:GY", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("328"), EnglishShortName = "Guyana", Name = "Guyana" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "HT", Alpha3 = "HTI", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:HT", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("332"), EnglishShortName = "Haiti", Name = "Haiti" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "HM", Alpha3 = "HMD", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:HM", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("334"), EnglishShortName = "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", Name = "Heard Island and McDonald Islands" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "VA", Alpha3 = "VAT", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:VA", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("336"), EnglishShortName = "Holy See", Name = "Holy See" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "HN", Alpha3 = "HND", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:HN", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("340"), EnglishShortName = "Honduras", Name = "Honduras" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "HK", Alpha3 = "HKG", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:HK", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("344"), EnglishShortName = "Hong Kong", Name = "Hong Kong" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "HU", Alpha3 = "HUN", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:HU", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("348"), EnglishShortName = "Hungary", Name = "Hungary" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "IS", Alpha3 = "ISL", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:IS", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("352"), EnglishShortName = "Iceland", Name = "Iceland" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "IN", Alpha3 = "IND", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:IN", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("356"), EnglishShortName = "India", Name = "India" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "ID", Alpha3 = "IDN", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:ID", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("360"), EnglishShortName = "Indonesia", Name = "Indonesia" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "IR", Alpha3 = "IRN", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:IR", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("364"), EnglishShortName = "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", Name = "Iran (Islamic Republic of)" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "IQ", Alpha3 = "IRQ", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:IQ", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("368"), EnglishShortName = "Iraq", Name = "Iraq" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "IE", Alpha3 = "IRL", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:IE", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("372"), EnglishShortName = "Ireland", Name = "Ireland" },
        new Entities.Country() { Alpha2 = "IM", Alpha3 = "IMN", ISO3166_2 = "ISO 3166-2:IM", NumericCode = Convert.ToInt32("833"), EnglishShortName = "Isle of Man", Name = "Isle of Man" }
}
}
```

Comment: Include what's needed for this post instead of having users find the other question themselves.

Comment: You should just post a few examples instead of spreading your method across multiple questions.

Comment: What kind of example would you like, this is  a "Seed" Method (populates database,using Code First EF)

Comment: I mean, you needn't have a zillion of these when they are all essentially the same: `new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-HER",  Code = "AF-HER", SubDivision = "Herat"                                 ,  Category = "province"                   },`

Comment: I see your point for brevity, but for detail I am including all the lines so that developers don't need to waste time typing countries or states (or generation) --

Comment: They won't.  Only a couple are needed to give the general idea - 10 would be more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to vertically align the arguments. It is a hassle to maintain. If you have to add a new long name it can cause changes to lines that aren't related, making diff's more cluttered.

You also included way more extra padding than necessary. It almost looks like you were trying to get `Category` to line up with `EnglishShortName`, but it is still off by a single character. Just stop wasting your time to try and make things like this "perfect".

---

Does `State` not have a constructor? If you are going to spend all this time to get an instance to be all on one line, why use the initializer format.

```
new Entities.State("AF-BDS", "AF-BDS", "Badakhshan", "province")
```

is much more readable than

```
new Entities.State() {  ISOCode ="AF-BDS",  Code = "AF-BDS", SubDivision = "Badakhshan"                            ,  Category = "province"                   }
```

If the arguments are unclear, you can always use named parameters. All of the horizontal scrolling make it very hard to work with.

---

You can write a function to remove the repeated code. Every `State`'s category is the same, but you explicitly list it out.

It looks like all the `ISOCode`s are the same as the `Code`s, no need to repeat that too.

```
private Entities.State MakeState(string isoCode, string subDivision)
{
    return new Entities.State() { ISOCode ="AF-BDS", Code = "AF-BDS", SubDivision = "Badakhshan",  Category = "province" };
}
```

Now the body is just:

```
States = new List<Entities.State>() 
{ 
    MakeState("AF-BDS", "Badakhshan"),
    MakeState("AF-BDG", "Badghis"),
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Unholysampler, I think that's exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate the comment. I will update and see what comes of it. (I will update my posts as well to reflect changes)

Comment: @jburto121 No, don't update your posts as that will invalidate answers.  You need to ask a follow-up question instead.